# Normalization of a healthcare database table which tracks the surgeries done

Tags: normalization, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, normalize

I have a table to track the surgeries in a hospital called `Surgery_Record` as below.

```
surgery_Record_ID   patient_ID    surgery_ID        theatre_ID     Surgery_Date
        1               1             20               0           2000-05-10
        2               85            20               0           2000-01-15
        3               10            20               0           2000-01-29
        4               13            16               0           2000-11-19
        5               15            1                0           2000-05-28
```

My assumptions are that:

1. No revisiting of patients
2. Every patient has only one surgery done
3. A particular operation Theatre is used only one time in a day

I figured out the following Functional Dependencies:

1. Patient_ID, Theatre_ID---> Surgery_Date
2. Surgery_Record_ID---> Patient_ID
3. Patient_ID---> Surgery_ID, Surgery_Record_ID, Theatre_ID
4. Patient_ID, Surgery_ID--->Theatre_ID
5. Surgery_Record_ID, Patient_ID, Surgery_ID, Theatre_ID---> Surgery_Date

From the above dependencies, I found that the candidate keys are {Patient_ID, Theatre_ID}
{Patient_ID, Surgery_ID} and {Surgery_Record_ID, Patient_ID, Surgery_ID, Theatre_ID}

So does my table violate the Second Normal Form? **Please help to check if my FDs are correct because i very new at doing this.** Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: None of those three assumptions are likely to be true in the real world. Does that matter?

Comment: hmm i thought those assumptions are the basis for my FDs because without them my FDs might not make sense so i thought of adding them.

Comment: Those assumptions might indeed be the basis for your FDs, but in the real world patients do revisit; they sometimes have more than one surgery at a time, sometimes using more than one surgical theater; and surgical theaters are available as quickly as they can be sterilized. If this is an academic exercise, it probably doesn't matter at all. If it's for a real hospital, it matters more.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall'- It is just for practice purposes. So my FDs are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FDs are in boldface.

---

- **Patient_ID, Theatre_ID---> Surgery_Date**

Based on the sample data, I'd have to say this one is wrong. The following FDs seem to be correct for these three attributes. They're derived mainly from your assumptions, which I've pointed out in comments probably don't hold in the real world.

- Patient_ID -> {Theatre_ID, Surgery_Date}
- Surgery_Date -> Theatre_ID

---

- **Surgery_Record_ID---> Patient_ID**

Each row gets a different value for Surgery_Record_ID, so Surgery_Record_ID determines every attribute.

- surgery_Record_ID -> {patient_ID, surgery_ID, theatre_ID, Surgery_Date}

---

- **Patient_ID---> Surgery_ID, Surgery_Record_ID, Theatre_ID**

Since patients can't revisit, and since patients can have only one surgery, Patient_ID will be globally unique, just like Surgery_Record_ID. Patient_ID will determine every attribute.

- patient_ID -> {surgery_Record_ID, surgery_ID, theatre_ID, Surgery_Date}

---

- **Patient_ID, Surgery_ID--->Theatre_ID**

I covered Patient_ID above. Surgery_ID doesnt' determine anything.

---

- **Surgery_Record_ID, Patient_ID, Surgery_ID, Theatre_ID---> Surgery_Date**
- Surgery_Record_ID -> {Patient_ID, Surgery_Date}
- Patient_ID -> {Surgery_Record_ID, Surgery_Date}
- Surgery_Date -> {Surgery_Record_ID, Patient_ID}

---

Your assumptions require Surgery_Date to be unique. So Surgery_Date determines every attribute.

- Surgery_Date -> {patient_ID, surgery_ID, theatre_ID, surgery_Record_ID}

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time and effort you put in to analyze my FDs.